# MySQL: get count value in joins and if else

Tags: mysql, sql

In My application I want to display all my friends and no of cheque given and received

```
Table Transaction                 Table Friends
----------------------------      -----------------------------
id  given_id   rev_id   amt        id  who_id  whom_id  who_name
-----------------------------     -------------------------------
 1    2          1       1k         1     1       2       sss
 2    2          3       1k         2     3       2       fff
 3.   3          2       2k         3     4       1       eee
 4    1          2       2k         4     2       1       iii
-----------------------------      ------------------------------

Result whom_id=2 name=iii  -> Friends (sss,fff) 
                            => sss gives totally 1 cheque and 
                               sss receives totally 1 cheque and
                               fff gives 1 cheque and
                               fff receives 1 cheque and
```

I tried This one..

```
SELECT 
p.who_id, 
p.who_name, 
COUNT( r1.give_id ) , 
COUNT( r1.rec_id ) 

FROM 
friends p 
LEFT JOIN Transaction r1 

ON p.who_id = r1.give_id OR p.who_id = r1.rec_id 

WHERE 
p.whom_id = 1 

GROUP BY p.who_id
```

Please provide me the best way to do this....

Comment: Well at least you said please :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer,

```
SELECT 
p.who_id, p.who_name, COUNT( r1.give_id ) , COUNT( r2.rec_id ) 

FROM 
friends p 
LEFT JOIN Transaction r1  ON p.who_id = r1.give_id 
LEFT JOIN Transaction r2  on p.who_id = r2.rec_id
WHERE 
p.whom_id = 1 

GROUP BY p.who_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select
  id,
  count(given_id) as given,
  count(rev_id) as reveive
from Friends
GROUP BY id;
```

and if you whant the  difference between the two amounts try this

```
select
  id,
  count(given_id) as given,
  count(rev_id) as reveive,
  given-receive as diff
from Friends
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HAVING with group  by ,
instead

```
WHERE p.whom_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this, both involve joining on the `Transactions` table twice.

You can use subqueries:

```
SELECT f.who_id,
  f.who_name,
  t1.TotalGiven,
  t2.TotalRev
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN
(
  select count(t.given_id) TotalGiven, t.given_id
  from Transactions t
  group by t.given_id
) t1
  ON f.who_id = t1.given_id 
LEFT JOIN
(
  select count(t.rev_id) TotalRev, t.rev_id
  from Transactions t
  group by t.rev_id
) t2
  ON f.who_id = t2.rev_id 
where f.whom_id = 2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f88eb/16).

Or you can just use a join with no subquery:

```
select f.who_id,
  f.who_name,
  count(t1.given_id) TotalGiven,
  count(t2.rev_id) TotalRev
FROM friends f
LEFT JOIN Transactions t1
  ON f.who_id = t1.given_id 
LEFT JOIN Transactions t2
  ON f.who_id = t2.rev_id 
where f.whom_id = 2
group by f.who_id,  f.who_name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f88eb/15)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT
  f.who_name,
  count(t.given_id)    GivenTotal,
  count(lt.rev_id) as RecievedTotal
from friends as f
  left join transaction as t
    on t.given_id = f.who_id
  left join transaction as lt
    on lt.rev_id   = f.who_id    
where f.whom_id = 2
group by t.given_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe578/1)

Output

```
who_name | GivenTotal | RecievedTotal 
----------------------------------
sss      |  1         |     1 
fff      |  1         |     1
```